# Obj-C, using ifndef and target parameters to only printf debug lines?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've been happily using a replacement for NSLog called DLog so that I don't have to worry about debugging being left in a release build.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", 
      [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);

#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

However, I'd like to do some a bit more complicated, I have numerous targets with debug parameters and I'd like to include two parameters to enable me to get debugging information.

I had hoped I could use, something like this...

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", ...
#else
#ifdef TESTFLIGHT && FREEMIUM
#   define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", ...
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

But it's not as simple as that.. I'm probably missing something obvious?

I've googled the problem but can't find the AND operator for this purpose and nested IF statements seems a problem too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "#elif" to make an else if, instead of nested ifs.

And you can can use the #if defined(TESTFLIGHT) && defined(FREEMIUM), as said on the other answers. So :

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#   define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", ...
#elif TESTFLIGHT && FREEMIUM
#   define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", ...
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the existence of the definition like this, to combine use this syntax:

```
#if defined TESTFLIGHT && defined FREEMIUM
```

(`#ifdef` is shorthand for `#if defined`).
Use `#elif` for "else if" to cascade without nesting.

---

You can use the boolean operator straight-up like you want if you're defining the constant to be equal to something (e.g. `1`) rather than just being "defined". e.g.

```
#define TESTFLIGHT 1
#define FREEMIUM   1

...

#if TESTFLIGHT && FREEMIUM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "normal" `#if`:

```
#if defined(TESTFLIGHT) && defined(FREEMIUM
```

`#ifdef FOO` is simply short for `#if defined(FOO)`

You're also missing an `#endif`. So complete, it's:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#  define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", ...
#else
#  if defined(TESTFLIGHT) && defined(FREEMIUM)
#    define DLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", ...
#  else
#    define DLog(...)
#  endif
#endif
```